# Java UDP Chat Application with two concurrent users

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, chat, datagram

I am trying to implement a chat application where two users(clients) can send and receive messages between each other. I have two classes (Server and Client), and can send messages between the clients successfully under certain circumstances. I have two problems with the program right now.

The first problem is that messages are only delivered successfully if the following steps are executed in this exact order:

1. Start one instance of the Server class, and then two instances of the Client class
2. Enter username for one of the clients(called client1 from here on)
3. Enter username for the other client(called client 2 from here on)
4. Send a message from the first client who connected to the server(client1)
5. Send a message from the second client who connected to the server(client2)
6. Continue having conversation until either client sends 'End_of_Communication'

If steps 5 and 6 are switched, so the second client sends a message before the first, the first client never gets that message. All subsequent messages are properly delivered, but I would like this first message to be delivered regardless of which client initiates conversation.

The second issue is with the 'End_of_Communication' string. If either client sends 'End_of_Communication' as a message, the server as well as both clients should display "[Username] has disconnected", and both clients should then terminate. The server should continue running, and print the initial "Listening for client requests" message.

Right now, the disconnection message is printed on both clients, but neither of the client programs actually terminate. The server does not print any disconnection message, and does not go to the top of the while loop. I suspect that this is because the client programs do not terminate, so the server blocks, waiting for 'clientThread[X].join()'. Code for both the Server and Client class are copy/pasted below.

Code for Server class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server {

    public static final int MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE = 255;        // Maximum size of datagram
    public static final String ECS = "End_of_Communication";        // End Communication String

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        byte[] clientData1 = new byte[MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];       // Buffer for first client requesting to connect
        byte[] clientData2 = new byte[MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];       // Buffer for second client requesting to connect
        DatagramPacket clientPacket1 = new DatagramPacket(clientData1, clientData1.length);     // Packet for first client requesting to connect
        DatagramPacket clientPacket2 = new DatagramPacket(clientData2, clientData2.length);     // Packet for second client requesting to connect
        DatagramSocket serverSocket;        // Socket for server to listen on
        int serverPort;     // Port to start serverSocket on
        int clientPort1;
        int clientPort2;
        Runnable clientRun1;        // Runnable object for first client requesting to connect
        Runnable clientRun2;        // Runnable object for second client requesting to connect
        Thread clientThread1;       // Thread for first client requesting to connect
        Thread clientThread2;       // Thread for second client requesting to connect
        String clientAlias1;        // Alias of first client requesting to connect
        String clientAlias2;        // Alias of second client requesting to connect

        // Check for correct # of arguments
        if(args.length != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s): <Port>");

        // Initialize serverPort and serverSocket
        serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort);

        // Loop forever and accept requests from clients
        while(true) {

            // Block until a client request is received, and get client alias and 
            System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "] | Listening for client requests... |");
            serverSocket.receive(clientPacket1);
            clientAlias1 = new String(clientPacket1.getData());
            clientPort1 = clientPacket1.getPort();
            System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "] | Connected to first client <" + clientAlias1 
                    + "> with socket address [" + clientPacket1.getSocketAddress() + "] |");

            // Block until a second client request is received, and get its alias
            serverSocket.receive(clientPacket2);
            clientAlias2 = new String(clientPacket2.getData());
            clientPort2 = clientPacket2.getPort();
            System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "] | Connected to second client <" + clientAlias2 
                    + "> with socket address [" + clientPacket2.getSocketAddress() + "] |");

            // Send clientAlias2 to first client
            clientData2 = clientAlias2.getBytes();
            clientPacket1.setData(clientData2);
            serverSocket.send(clientPacket1);
            // Send clientAlias1 to second client
            clientData1 = clientAlias1.getBytes();
            clientPacket2.setData(clientData1);
            serverSocket.send(clientPacket2);

            // Send second client's port to first client
            clientData2 = String.valueOf(clientPort2).getBytes();
            clientPacket1.setData(clientData2);
            serverSocket.send(clientPacket1);

            clientData1 = String.valueOf(clientPort1).getBytes();
            clientPacket2.setData(clientData1);
            serverSocket.send(clientPacket2);

            // Create a new thread for each client request received
            clientRun1 = new ServerThread(serverSocket, clientPacket1, clientPacket2, clientAlias1);
            clientThread1 = new Thread(clientRun1);
            clientRun2 = new ServerThread(serverSocket, clientPacket2, clientPacket1, clientAlias2);
            clientThread2 = new Thread(clientRun2);

            // Start each thread
            clientThread1.start();
            clientThread2.start();

            // Wait for threads to finish before looping again
            try{
                clientThread1.join();
                clientThread2.join();
            } catch(InterruptedException interrupt) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException: " + interrupt);
            }// End try/catch block

        }// End while loop
    }// End main

    private static String getTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

}// End Server

/*************************************End Server**************************************/
/*************************************************************************************/
/*********************************Start ServerThread**********************************/

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    protected DatagramSocket socket;
    protected DatagramPacket readPacket;
    protected DatagramPacket writePacket;
    protected InetAddress readAddress;
    protected InetAddress writeAddress;
    protected int readPort;
    protected int writePort;
    protected String userName;

    public ServerThread(DatagramSocket serverSocket, DatagramPacket readPacket, DatagramPacket writePacket, String userName) {
        this.socket = serverSocket;
        this.readPacket = readPacket;
        this.writePacket = writePacket;
        this.readAddress = readPacket.getAddress();
        this.writeAddress = writePacket.getAddress();
        this.readPort = readPacket.getPort();
        this.writePort = writePacket.getPort();
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String message;
            byte[] readBytes = new byte[Server.MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
            byte[] writeBytes = new byte[Server.MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];

            while(true) {

                // Create byte array to read data from packet into
                readBytes = new byte[Server.MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
                readPacket = new DatagramPacket(readBytes, readBytes.length, readAddress, readPort);

                // Block until packet is received, and extract its data
                socket.receive(readPacket);
                if(readPacket.getPort() == writePort)
                    continue;
                message = new String(readPacket.getData());
                if(message.equals(Server.ECS))
                    System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "] | <" + userName + "> has disconnected. |");
                readBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(readPacket.getData(), readPacket.getOffset(), readPacket.getOffset()+readPacket.getLength());

                // Create byte array to write extracted data to
                writeBytes = new byte[Server.MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
                writeBytes = readBytes;
                writePacket = new DatagramPacket(writeBytes, writeBytes.length, writeAddress, writePort);

                // Send the packet to its destination
                socket.send(writePacket);


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String getTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }


}
```

Code for Client class:

```
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Client {

    public static final int MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE = 255;        // Maximum size of datagram
    public static final String ECS = "End_of_Communication";        // End Communication String

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));        // BufferedReader to get user input
        byte[] myData = new byte[MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
        byte[] clientData = new byte[MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
        DatagramSocket clientSocket;        // Socket for this client to connect to server
        DatagramPacket myDataPacket;
        DatagramPacket clientDataPacket;
        InetAddress serverIP;       // IP address of server
        int serverPort;     // Port that server is listening on
        int clientPort;     // Port to send messages to
        WriteThread write;      // Thread to write data to the server
        ReadThread read;        // Thread to read data from the server
        String userName;        // Alias to use for this client
        String clientName;      // Alias to use for other client

        // Check for correct # of arguments
        if((args.length < 1) || (args.length > 2))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s): <Server> [<Port>]");

        // Create DatagramSocket on specified port and IP address
        serverIP = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
        serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        // Connect the socket the server 
        clientSocket.connect(serverIP, serverPort);

        // Collect data to connect
        System.out.println("Please enter username(No Spaces): [Guest]");
        userName = userInput.readLine();
        if(userName.isEmpty())
            userName = "Guest";

        System.out.println("| Username set to <" + userName + ">. Sending to server... |");
        myData = userName.getBytes();

        // Send packet with userName to server
        myDataPacket = new DatagramPacket(myData, myData.length, serverIP, serverPort);
        clientSocket.send(myDataPacket);

        // Create packet to receive data about the other client from the server
        clientDataPacket = new DatagramPacket(clientData, clientData.length);
        clientDataPacket.setLength(MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE);
        clientSocket.receive(clientDataPacket);
        clientName = new String(clientDataPacket.getData());
        clientData = new byte[MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
        clientDataPacket = new DatagramPacket(clientData, clientData.length);
        clientDataPacket.setLength(MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE);
        clientSocket.receive(clientDataPacket);
        clientPort = Integer.parseInt((new String(clientDataPacket.getData())).trim());

        // Create and start threads to write to and read data from the server
        write = new WriteThread(clientSocket, serverPort, userName);
        read = new ReadThread(clientSocket, clientName);
        write.start();
        read.start();

        // Wait for threads to finish
        try {
            write.join();
            read.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException interrupt) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException: " + interrupt);
        }// End try/catch block

    }// End main
}// End Client

/*************************************End Client**************************************/
/*************************************************************************************/
/**********************************Start WriteThread**********************************/

class WriteThread extends Thread implements Runnable {

    protected InetAddress serverIP;     // IP address of the server
    protected int serverPort;       // Port server is listening on
    protected DatagramSocket writeSocket;       // DatagramSocket to SEND data to server
    protected String userName;

    public WriteThread(DatagramSocket clientSocket, int serverPort, String userName) {
        this.writeSocket = clientSocket;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        this.serverIP = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String writeString;
            byte[] writeBytes;
            DatagramPacket writePacket;

            while(true) {
                writeBytes = new byte[Client.MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
                writeString = userInput.readLine();
                writeBytes = writeString.getBytes();
                writePacket = new DatagramPacket(writeBytes, writeBytes.length, serverIP, serverPort);
                writeSocket.send(writePacket);
                if((writeString).equals(Client.ECS))
                    break;
                System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "]<" + userName + "> " + new String(writePacket.getData()));
            }// End while

            // End_of_Communiation received, print disconnect message
            System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "] | <" + userName + "> has disconnected. |");
            writeBytes = new byte[Client.MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];
            writeBytes = writeString.getBytes();
            writePacket = new DatagramPacket(writeBytes, writeBytes.length, serverIP, serverPort);
            writeSocket.send(writePacket);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ex);
        }// End try/catch block
    }// End run()

    private String getTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

}// End writeThread

/***********************************End WriteThread***********************************/
/*************************************************************************************/
/**********************************Start ReadThread***********************************/

class ReadThread extends Thread implements Runnable {

    protected InetAddress serverIP;     // IP address of the server
    protected int serverPort;       // Port server is listening on
    protected DatagramSocket clientSocket;      // DatagramSocket to READ data to server
    protected String clientName;

    public ReadThread(DatagramSocket clientSocket, String clientName) throws SocketException {
        this.serverIP = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
        this.serverPort = clientSocket.getPort();
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            byte[] readData = new byte[Server.MAXIMUM_DATAGRAM_SIZE];       // Buffer for data READ from server
            DatagramPacket readPacket;      // Packet to READ data to server
            String readMessage;     // String of the message READ from server

            // Loop until user requests disconnect
            while(true) {


                // Set up datagram packet to READ from server
                readPacket = new DatagramPacket(readData, readData.length);

                // Wait for a packet to READ from server
                clientSocket.receive(readPacket);

                // Extract and print message READ from server
                readMessage = new String(readPacket.getData(), 0, readPacket.getLength());
                if(readMessage.equals(Client.ECS))
                    break;
                System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "]<" + clientName + "> " + readMessage);
            }// End while

            // End_of_Communication received, exit
            System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "] | <" + clientName + "> has disconnected. |");

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("IOException caught: " + ex);
        }// End try/catch block
        return;
    }// End run

    private String getTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

}// End readThread
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is you aren't closing your sockets. This means even though no data is being transferred the connection is still alive.

It is important with any IO you properly handle the closing behavior so connections aren't left alive. This is most commonly done with a try, catch, finally block. Take your `ReadThread` for example

```
try {
    // Loop until user requests disconnect
    while(true) {
            //...bla bla...
    }// End while

    // End_of_Communication received, exit
    System.out.println("[" + getTime() + "] | <" + clientName + "> has disconnected. |");

} catch(IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("IOException caught: " + ex);
} finally {
    // here we want to close the socket. 
    //Even if an exception is thrown we always want to make sure that the client connection is terminated.
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

I would bet that if you close all your clients your problem will disappear. Plus its always important to get into a habit of properly closing resources after you are finished with them.

If you want to know more about the try, catch finally block you can read about it here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: I added the finally block to the end of each try/catch that involved a socket, and put '[X]Socket.close()' in the finally block where [X] is the name of the socket. I thought that because UDP is connectionless that it wouldn't matter if the socket was left open, but I now see where my mistake was.

However this only causes the client who SENDS 'End_of_Communication' to terminate, while the other client remains running. I have tried removing both the write/read.join() calls, and removing each one individually but am still stuck.

Comment: @trawww how about storing your connected clients on the server and closing them all when one disconnects. Another option is to terminate the server when one client leaves